# Validation fails if input is not number

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I have an MVC 5.2.3 project.  I am using data annotations including a remote data validation annotation that is only validated on the server.  The remote validation checks the inputs with a number stored on the server as well as checking it vs the other numbers entered.
In addition I have a field on the client which shows the sum of all the numbers entered.
This works fine as long as no non-digit characters are entered.  If I entered "5,000" then the validation is not performed.  I added a line to my javascript that strips the commas from the text box.  The script works fine in a stand alone html page, but does not work with my mvc page. The js $validator.setDefaults({onkeyup: false}); is necessary for the remote validation to work properly so removing this is not an option. Also I have tried adding a regedit validation annotation but it is not fired (probably because I turned off the onkeyup event).

Putting a breakpoint at the start of the function, if the value entered is numeric than the value for a.value is what was inputted.  If the value entered had commas or other not digit characters then then a.value is empty.
Why is this so?

Here is my javascript:

```
 $.validator.setDefaults({ onkeyup: false });
$('.sumup').blur(function (a) { addvalue(this); });         
    });

    function addvalue(a) {
        var sum = 0;
        var dsum = 0;
        var b = a.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        a.value = b;
        $('.sumup').
           each(function () {
               if ($.isNumeric($(this).val()))
               { sum += parseInt($(this).val()); }
           });
        $('#total').html(sum.toCurrencyString());

        $('#totaldirect').html(dsum.toCurrencyString());

    }
    Number.prototype.toCurrencyString = function () {
        return this.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, '$1,');
    }
```

This is my razor script:

```
 <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentFR.Salaries, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})</th>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentFR.Salaries, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control col-md-2 sumup", id = "saltb"}})
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentFR.Salaries, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>

             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReportedToDate.Salaries, new {htmlAttributes=new {id="salariesTD"}})</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BudgetToDate.Salaries, new {htmlAttributes = new {id="salariesBTD"}})</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentFR.Operations, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})

            </th>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentFR.Operations, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control sumup", id = "opertb"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentFR.Operations, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReportedToDate.Operations)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BudgetToDate.Operations)</td>
        </tr>  ....
```

This is my data model for these fields:

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "${0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    //[RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Number, No comma's or periods")]
    [Remote("ValidateSalary", "FiscalReports", HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = "Counter, FiscalYear",
        ErrorMessage = "The budget to date cannot be exceeded by more than $5,000")]
    public int? Salaries { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "${0:N0}"]
    [Remote("ValidateOperations", "FiscalReports", HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = "Counter, FiscalYear",
        ErrorMessage = "The budget to date cannot be exceeded by more than $5,000")]
    public int? Operations { get; set; }
```

Comment: You replace any character which is not a digit with empty character: `var b = a.value.replace(/\D/g, '');`

Comment: That is the intention and it is in line 3 of my code.  But the inputted text is not passed to 'a' if there is a non digit character.   This code works in a stand alone html page but not in the configuration described above.